# How to change datetime to numeric discarding 0s at end

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have dataset with subscription activation date and subscription end date. I converted both of them into datetime and subtacted to get the days of subscription

df['SUBSCRIPTION_ACTIVATION_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SUBSCRIPTION_ACTIVATION_DATE'])

f['SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE'])

df['SUBSCRIPTION_DAY'] = df['SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE'] - df['SUBSCRIPTION_ACTIVATION_DATE']

Now I am trying to convert it into integer and it is taking HH:MM:SS also and creating integer adding 0s at end. I am using below command

df['SUBSCRIPTION_DAY'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SUBSCRIPTION_DAY'])

ex: 215827200000000000

How to get rid of those o's and get only days

Comment: Use `df['SUBSCRIPTION_DAY'] = (df['SUBSCRIPTION_END_DATE'] - df['SUBSCRIPTION_ACTIVATION_DATE']).dt.days`